# angular 4 with type script object variables setting to null when calling from method

Tags: angular, typescript

I created angular 4 app with following component as below.

```
<div></div>
<p>d3 works!</p>
<button (click)="getCommitData()">button1</button>
<label style="display: block">{{data}}</label>

import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-d3',
  templateUrl: './d3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./d3.component.css']
})
export class D3Component {
  user: String = 'angular';
  repo: String = 'angular.js';
  data: String;
  error: String;
  url: string;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + this.user +
      '/' +
      this.repo +
      '/commits';
  }

  humanReadableDate(d: Date): String {
    return d.getUTCMonth() + 1 + '/' + d.getUTCDate();
  }

  reformatGITResponse(data: String[]): any {
    return data;
  }

  handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

  getCommitData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise()
      .then(response => this.reformatGITResponse(response.json().data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AngularAppSimple</title>
<base href="/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <app-d3></app-d3>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i call getCommitData() from component.html I'm getting null for both *url and http* variables in *getCommitData method above*. But when initiating constructor is being called and the url variable is being set.

How the type script objects get injected ?

Also how shall i display the data returned from *getCommitData method* above ?

Comment: I would reccomend using ngOnInit to init variables. "this.user" and "this.repo" may not be availabe in the constructor

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: post your html content

Comment: added html content.

Comment: your code looks fine check it  here http://plnkr.co/edit/bZqa7Y87mFxpTfCWYU9Y?p=preview check your browsers console there may be some errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @mwe pointed out, do it in ngOnInit ro perhaps the constructor, do not call it directrly from html template as the variables may not be resolved.

try something like

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + this.user +
      '/' +
      this.repo +
      '/commits';
      this.getCommitData();
  }

  getCommitData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
      **this.loading = false;**
      return this.reformatGITResponse(response.json().data)
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

basically call the rest api, from constructro than wait until it finishes, and mark it with some flag like LOADING. On the template you can display whole page using `ngIf=!loading`

Comment: Also as an additional to note that the constructor method will be called once and when the object is create. So the `this.getCommitData();` will be called once throughout the entire Angular app cycle. So the best place to place it if you want the `this.getCommitData();` to be called each time the component is loaded on screen is in the ngOnInit

Comment: On calling getCommitData from onInit and construtor the variables are getting initiated but when clicking on the button <button (click)="this.getCommitData()">button1</button> it still getting url and http  as null.

Comment: `<button (click)="this.getCommitData()">` should be `<button (click)="getCommitData()">`

Comment: @user5500750 really it is the case? I thought that once I let say change view (with routing), the component will get destroyed, thus when I return it will be constructed once again

Comment: @pezetem Not always, angular by default uses a component reuse strategy which reuses the components if the current and future routes are the same. For example you have a route `/posts/:id` with comonent `PostComponent` and route from `/posts/1` to `/posts/2` then angular will resuse the `PostComponent`. But the explanation from user5500750 wasn't right either.

Comment: it is working but in debugger somehow it is showing null;